# send data query through local file in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So on my localhost I can send data quite simply by doing:

`http://localhost:8080/folder1/folder2/?q=My_Data` and then within `folder2` I have an `index.html` file with a `js` file attached to it that uses the following code to extract the query:

`var data = getUrlParameter('q');`

Now this works perfectly fine, but when I put those into my chrome extension I was hoping I could read the parameters in the same way like this:

`chrome-extension://MYID/folder1/folder2/?q=My_Data` but that doesn't work, it shows a 404. If I replace `?q=My_Data` with simply `index.html` the page loads and if I add `index.html?q=My_Data` it again shows a 404 message.

Am I missing something? What else could I try? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My apologies. I have found the mistake. I didn't apply the `content_script_policy` with the correct API URL I was using.